# How to Iterate over angular json object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have created a nodejs application that will read all the databases in my mongo Db. Which i am able to do in the console. However, when i try too get the data parsed to a json object and dispaly it to the screen, i cant manage to get the info to display. Hopeing someone can help me figure out how or tell me what im doing wrong. Thanks

app.js

```
// listen for get request, aka transfers the info in mongo to client
app.get('/databases', function (req, res) {
    console.log("-- recived GET request --"); 
    db.open(function(err, db) {

      // Use the admin database for the operation
      var adminDb = db.admin();

      // List all the available databases
      adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        assert.ok(dbs.databases.length > 0);
        console.log(dbs);
        res.json(dbs); 
        db.close();
      });
    });
});
```

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("controller connected");

function refresh(){ 
// create route 
$http.get('/databases').success(function(response) {
    console.log("recived data requested");
    $scope.databases = response; 
  });
}

// Call refresh to get req
refresh(); 

});// Controller
```

index.html

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="contact in databases">
    {{ contact }}
  </li>
</ul>
 <button type="button" onclick="hitMe()">Click Me!</button> 
</div>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try and add another ng-repeat, and then repeat throught contract.names or contact.Sizeof

Comment: can step through your code and see how your response look like? In same cases you'll need to get data property from response: $scope.databases = response.data; (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage - response object)

Comment: Yeah Andrew i tried that. didn’t work. punov had the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to iterate through datebases.databases object.
As soon as $scope.databases is:

```
{
 databases: [],
 totalSize: ..,
 ..
}
```

you need the following ng-repeat on your page:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="contact in databases.databases">
    {{ contact.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: O thanks. This worked. What does the 'databases.databases' do ?

Comment: I just noticed, that somehow in your databases ($scope.databases = response) object, when you consoled it, you have 'databases' field. And only this field contains array of contacts

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew said try contact.name in your html code.

"contact" on its own would be the entire object. you have to specify what part of the object you want to use.